# Same table with the same packages lead to different footnote alignments

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage, alignment

I have added the exact same table (code below) to the [ACM sigconf template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) as well as the [IEEE conference template](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html). I have also added the same packages to these templates (`multirow`, `array`, `makecell` & `caption`). Nevertheless, the footnote is aligned as expected (center) in the ACM template:

[image: ACM template output]

but not in the IEEE template:

[image: IEEE template output]

Table code:

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.37}
  \centering
  \caption{Table Title}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \Xhline{0.5pt}
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Classification}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Col 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Col 2} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col 3\footnote{Its information is this and that.}} \\
        \cline{2-10}
          & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T4} \\
        \Xhline{0.5pt}
    Category and Type of Row One & 4     & 26    & 5    & 2     & 16     & 8     & 64     & 32    & 12 \\
        \Xhline{0.5pt}
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:T1}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
```

How can I align the footnote to the center in the IEEE template?

Comment: Why not use `\textsuperscript{\itshape a}` where your `\footnote` command currently is and place `\multicolumn{10}{c}{\textsuperscript{\itshape a}Its information is this and that.}` directly before  `\end{tabular}`?

Comment: Regarding the use of `\captionsetup` from the `caption` package: If you want to publish a paper in either of the two journals/conferences, it is better to just stick to their caption formatting style instead of trying to change it. At least `IEEEtran`'s documentation explicitly states not being compatible with the `caption` package. Regarding the table design: Depending on the journal, different styles of tables are preferred. The ' acmart'`s documentation explicitly highlights their preference for `booktabs`-like tables without vertical and just a few horizontal lines.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. It works! However, for some reason, I would still prefer to fix it without changing the table itself, if possible?

Comment: How or where is `\Xhline` defined?

Comment: @Mico I think it is a part of the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to echo @leandriis' comment that you should refrain from using the `caption` package when using the `IEEEtran` document class.

I'd like to suggest a solution that's different from either of the two you've encountered so far. It uses the [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable) package to place the footnotes flush-left below the `tabular` material.

Here's the look that results from using the `acmart` document class:

[image]

And here's the look that results from using the `IEEEtran` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}%{acmart}%
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \caption{Table Title} \label{tab:T1}
  \begin{tabular}{ |l| *{9}{c|} }
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Classification}} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Col 1} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Col 2} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col 3\tnote{a}} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T4}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
    Category and Type of Row One 
    & 4 & 26 & 5 & 2 & 16 & 8 & 64 & 32 & 12 \\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
  \end{tabular}
  
  \smallskip\footnotesize
  \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
  \item[a]Its information is this and that.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For information, you can draw that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has its own built-in system for tabular notes (with a command `\tabularnote`).

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \caption{Table Title} \label{tab:T1}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ |l|*{9}{c|} }
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
    \Block{2-1}{\textbf{Classification}} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Col 1} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col 2} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Col 3\tabularnote{Its information is this and that.}} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T4}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
    Category and Type of Row One 
    & 4 & 26 & 5 & 2 & 16 & 8 & 64 & 32 & 12 \\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Excepted the caption, the output is the same with the class `acmart`.

---

If you don't bother with horizontal rules of thickness 0.5 pt (the default value is 0.4 pt), you can, with `{NiceTabular}`, draw all the rules with one key `hvlines`.

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \caption{Table Title} \label{tab:T1}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ l*{9}{c} }[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{\textbf{Classification}} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Col 1} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col 2} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Col 3\tabularnote{Its information is this and that.}} \\
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T3} 
    & \textbf{T1} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} & \textbf{T4}\\
    Category and Type of Row One 
    & 4 & 26 & 5 & 2 & 16 & 8 & 64 & 32 & 12 \\
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}
```